# Tengo un pequeño problema, a la hora de hacer el map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Tengo un pequeño problema, a la hora de hacer el map me hace los console, pero cuando quiero sacar los articulos me dice que el if esperaba otra cosa,creo que es por el tipado. Pero no le encuentro la solucion.
El error es este:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
 class ViewCategori extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
      constructor(props: IProps) {
          super(props)

          this.state = {
              article: []

          }
      }
      render() {

          const { article } = this.state;

          const { login } = this.props;



        return (*

                       {article.map(article => {
                                  if (article?.categori === "1") {
                                      console.log("article._id")

                                      // <h1>{article.name}</h1>
                                      // <div className="card styleard" >
                                      //     <img className="card-img-top" src={`http://localhost:5000/avatars/${article.img}`} alt="Card image cap" />
                                      //     <div className="card-body" key={article._id}>
                                      //         <h5 className="card-title">{article.name}</h5>
                                      //         <p className="card-text">{article.description}</p>
                                      //     </div>
                                      // </div>
                                  }
                              })}
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho a tu pregunta agregues el mensaje de error exacto que estás obteniendo

Comment: Amigo Jorge, has nombrado a la variable dentro del map igual que a la variable del state, quizá te ayudaría a depurar usar nombres diferentes.